# How to detect when Crystal Report print button in being triggered?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How can I access the `Print` control button in the Crystal Report and put an `event` on it. I'm using `VB.NET` Visual Studio 2010 WinForm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have access to this in your Version of Crystal Reports, but in v7 you can reference the Crystal Report Engine Automation Server from which you can create a Window Object, (The Preview Screen for the Report), defining this WithEvent allows you to intercept the Preview Window Events.

```
   Private oCrystal As New CRPEAuto.Application
Private oReport As CRPEAuto.Report
Private WithEvents oWindow As CRPEAuto.Window

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set oReport = oCrystal.OpenReport("C:\Report1.rpt")
    Set oWindow = oReport.Preview("Report Title").Parent
End Sub

Private Sub oWindow_PrintButtonClicked(UseDefault As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Print Clicked"
End Sub
```